# How to trigger Material UI Select Component OnChange immediately upon rendering the component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drop-down-menu

I have a select component that is loaded with options, a selected Key and Value.

```
<Select
   id={props.id}
   data-testid={props.id}
   key={props.selectedKey}
   value={props.selectedValue}
   variant="outlined"
   size="small"
   onChange={props.onChange}
   disabled={props.disabled}>
     {props.options.map((option) => (
        <MenuItem id={props.id} key={option.key} value={option.key}>
           {option.label}
        </MenuItem>
     ))}
</Select>
```

My goal is to execute the onChange immediately for the first time when the component is loaded with options. Is there a way to manually trigger the onChange immediately after loading the options? My application handles the select component option changes perfectly, but whenever there is only single option dynamically provided to the Select component, choosing that single option does not automatically trigger the onChange of the select component.

I tried to trigger the code block from result of onChange manually when the component renders initially(which involves using react hooks), and it ended causing the following issue

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```